Mentally ill man who kills people when he hears music
Saw this movie several years ago, I can't find it anymore since it is a not very well known movie...

Not sure but I think setting was in France;
Protagonist is mentally ill and goes absolutely mad when he hears any kind of music;
He starts killing when he hears music;
There was one (or were it two?) girls who tried to seduce him, but he killed her (or both?) when music started to play;
At the end of the movie, he tried to escape from someone (maybe the police?). There was a ridiculous scene, he dressed as a nun (or old grandma?) and was driving away in his car. Camera was showing the window of the car and he suddenly turned his face into the camera.

It's gonna be hard to find this movie because it was a really unknown movie, but maybe someone knows it!

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Sounds like Discopath, a French-Canadian thriller from 2013.

The film is about Duane Lewis, a New York cook who becomes insane when hearing disco music. After murdering a woman in a club, Duane travels to Montreal where he continues his killing spree.

Near the end, he tries to kills some people at a funeral disguised as a nun and attempts to escape. Here's the trailer:



